# How can you add a fixed placeholder text in a Flutter textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

Im looking for a way to show an example of a text input expected in a TextFormField in Flutter, the idea would be similar to using a hintText, but this hint not disappearing and adapting to the users input, i do not need formatting or anything.

I tried putting one textFormField stacked on another but this hacky way creates new issues that i cannot resolve.

The exprected result would be similar to the following image:

[image: Expected Result]

Code Snippet:

```
Stack(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          scrollController: scrollController,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          controller: textController,
          keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            labelText: "label",
            hintText: "Hint",
            fillColor: white,
          ),
        ),
        if (IsTextFormSelected)
          TextFormField(
            scrollController: secondScrollController,
            focusNode: secondFocusNode,
            controller: secondController,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              // RequestsFocus from mainTextFormField onTap
              focusNode.requestFocus();
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
```

I would really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Add your code snippet

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Added a Code Snippet, thanks!

Comment: Why you declare two Text fields in stack just used one

Comment: Try this package -> https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code using Single TextField:

```
TextFormField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "label",
        hintText: "Hint",
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        fillColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for you're response but that's not the wanted result, as you write the hint disappears, I have found a cleanish solution and will be adding to this question.